# How can I reference an existing entry to a new entity in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I working on the following Models:

- User
- Category

One `User` can only get one `Category`. Categories are "standalone". So I can update, create and delete (okay, maybe with cascading) Categories whenever I want.

When I create a new `User`, I want do reference one `Category` to the `User`.
How can I do so? I want to avoid bad practices.

`User` entity:

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    //...
}
```

`Category` entity:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 *       @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $user;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write a `User` can have one `Category`, but it seems from your description that a `Category` can be used by several users. If this is true then your category definition should be changed a bit:

```
/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // It is important to initialize your collection
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // add methods for adding/removing and getting users:
    // addUser, removeUser, addUsers, removeUsers and getUsers method
}
```

Read more on initializing collections in the doctrine documentation chapter **[27.7. Initialize collections in the constructor](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor)**.

Then in your `User` class you will need methods for setting and getting category.

```
public function setCategory(Category $category)
{
    $category->addUser($user);
    $this->category = $category;
}

public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->category;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$category = // get the category you want to set from entity manager
$user = new User();
$user->setCategory($category);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Now both your user and category are correctly set.
This is just a basic example that will help you get on your way.